# How to check if list's elements are contiguous

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have to check if ■ are contiguous:

```
_|_ _|_1_|_2_|_3_|_
_|_1_|_■_|_■_|_ _|_
_|_2_|_ _|_ _|_■_|_
_|_3_|_ _|_■_|_ _|_
_|_4_|_■_|_■_|_ _|_
```

in this case return True

and for example if something like this happens:

```
_|_ _|_1_|_2_|_3_|_
_|_1_|_■_|_■_|_ _|_
_|_2_|_ _|_ _|_■_|_
_|_3_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_4_|_■_|_■_|_ _|_
```

in this case return False

I'm using lists like:

```
my_list=[[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "],
[" "," "," "]]
```

The numbers appear only when printing the board, so I work anything else with my_list.

Comment: Do you mean contiguous? Because they are already all adjacent to another box in your second example too.

Comment: Are diagonals considered adjacent?

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant contiguous.

Comment: Yes, for me in this case, diagonals are considered adjacent.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 5):

Walk the graph, and if you visit every node then you are connected (contiguous), e.g.:

```
def is_contiguous(grid):
    items = {(x, y) for x, row in enumerate(grid) for y, f in enumerate(row) if f}
    directions = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]
    neighbours = {(x, y): [(x+dx, y+dy) for dx, dy in directions if (x+dx, y+dy) in items]
                  for x, y in items}

    closed = set()
    fringe = [next(iter(items))]
    while fringe:
        i = fringe.pop()
        if i in closed:
            continue
        closed.add(i)
        for n in neighbours[i]:
            fringe.append(n)

    return items == closed

>>> is_contiguous([["X", "X", ""], ["", "", "X"], ["", "X", ""], ["X", "X", ""]])
True
>>> is_contiguous([["X", "X", ""], ["", "", "X"], ["", "", ""], ["X", "X", ""]])
False
```

As long as a blank tile is falsy then this should work as is, e.g. `[[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]` would also return `True`. If you have a different definition of a blank tile then just change `if f` on the `items` definition.

Answer (score 2):

I will not give you the code that you can just insert (because it looks to me like a programming challenge), but I will give you the idea how to solve your problem.

You need to construct a graph. So for every black dot, you have the list of adjacent black dots (you define here what is adjacent). For example if all diagonals count as such, then for point `(2, 3)` your adjacent list will be: `(1, 2), (3, 2)`. And your graph will look like

```
{
  (2, 3): {(1, 2), (3, 2)},
  ... every other node
}
```

You can come up with a simpler schema, where `(2, 3)` will correspond to `(2 - 1) * len(matrix row) + (3 - 1) = 5`. I am subtracting one because I use zero as a starting point.

Now when you have a graph, you use the algorithm for a [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) and check whether there is only one such component. If it is, you get True, otherwise false.

Your single connected component is just a BFS or DFS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def findContiguous(myList):
    rowCount = 0
    previousRowFound = []
    rowsWithItems = []     
    for row in myList:
        currentRowFound = []
        rowCount += 1
        # Determine if target is in the row
        if "■" in row:
            currentRowFound = [i for i, x in enumerate(row) if x == "■"]
            rowsWithItems.append(rowCount)

        # Check if there is a cell adjacent or diagonal to previous
        if len(currentRowFound) != 0 and len(previousRowFound) != 0:
            for cell in currentRowFound:
                if not((cell + 1 in previousRowFound) or (cell - 1 in previousRowFound) or (cell in previousRowFound)):
                    return False

        # Check for blank rows in between rows with item
        if len(rowsWithItems) > 1 and len(previousRowFound) == 0:
            if rowsWithItems[-2] != rowCount - 1:
                print(rowsWithItems)
                print(rowCount)
                return False

        # Move on to next row
        previousRowFound = currentRowFound
        first = False
    return True
```

Comment: I've not tried to run this, but doesn't this just check that every cell has an adjacent neighbor?  What if there is a pair of adjacent cells that are not connected to the rest?  Add a cell at 3,1 in the OP's test case, and see if you still get the answer False.

Comment: Yes, I have performed this test and it still yields a false. The function checks for an adjacent neighbor in the row previous, so in your suggested change, the disjoint between rows 2 and 3 would be detected and return a false

Comment: How about two columns of cells in column 1 and 3?

Comment: If this is what you're talking about `my_list=[["■"," ","■"],["■"," ","■"],["■"," ","■"],
["■"," ","■"]]` then it returns true

Comment: I think it should return False, since there is no connection between the two groups. Also, if there is an otherwise contiguous case that leaves the top or bottom row empty, you return False when it should be True.

Comment: To your first point, I don't see how it should be false since both groups are connected vertically. As to your second, I realize that I misinterpreted OP's question and was not considering  "island" cases as true cases. I will push the fix shortly

Comment: code now accepts island cases that should have been true

Comment: Well, only the OP can tell since his description of "contiguous" seems to have multiple interpretations. I would think 2 vertical groups separated by an empty column would fail the "all X are contiguous" test. I interpreted "contiguous" to mean "I can get to any X from any other X". Here's a thought experiment: should the test return the same True or False value if the graph is rotated or transposed? In Python, it is easy to get the transpose of a list of lists: `trans_list = zip(*original_list)`  If you transpose the case of 2 vertical columns, I'm pretty sure that will fail your test.

Comment: If using Python 3, you'll need to write `trans_list = list(zip(*original_list))`

Comment: I see what you're saying. I appreciate all the feedback you've given, but I think I will call it here until OP adds a comment about his definition of contiguous